# Can't see indexedDB database in mozilla developer tools

Tags: configuration, indexeddb, usability, firefox-developer-tools

I can't see the DB I created in indexedDB in Mozilla developer tools.
The DB is properly created and with data stored in it because it's possible to retrive them, but doesn't appear in the tools section for indexedDB.
Does anybody know why is that and/or how to solve it?
Is Mozilla v.40
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would love to help if you can give me some way to access the database. I am assigned to the storage inspector in Firefox DevTools so I won't have a problem finding out what the problem is.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the late answer and thanks a lot for offering your help. I'm a complete rookie in web development and I'm trying to learn while practicing. I want to develp an app for a professional environment where would be ideal to use as less as possible the internet conection due to its slowness. That's what i wanted to use indexedDB. I'm not used to this platform and i don't know how to do it, but I have no problem for you to check the code. how can i send it?

Comment: Can send you a google drive link...

Comment: I had the exact same problem, and I was able to view the indexedDb contents very nicely in `Chrome->More Tools->Developer Tools->Resources`. That was enough for my purposes.  

It could also be that now firefox has fixed this issue, at least end of last year I couldn't view it in firefox, but now, with Iceweasel 38.4 I can.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today in Firefox 91 under Linux, despite it being [allegedly fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1291655) five years ago.  I found that the workaround posted back then, namely to close and re-open the developer tools (in my case I pressed F12 twice) somehow got the storage state back in sync and my newly created database showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a reason for the not functioning of the display of the added records in the developer console of the Mozilla Firefox browser.  Indeed when you hard wire the Java Script code in the html page instead of using include files the added storing media are no longer correctly recognized.

Indeed replacing

```
      <!--------------------- INCLUDE FILES --------------------->
      <script src="db.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
      <!--------------------- INCLUDE FILES --------------------->
      </body>
```

which works correctly on all SSD drives, by the following
same code included on the same spot in the html page:

```
<!--------------------- INCLUDE FILES --------------------->
  <script> // src="db.js">   
    <!--------------------- content of src="db.js" --------------------->
  </script>
  <script> // src="app.js">   
    <!--------------------- content of src="app.js" --------------------->
  </script>
<!--------------------- INCLUDE FILES --------------------->
```

NO LONGER SHOW UP in developer console but still work correctly on SSD Drive

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Storage Inspector, available in Firefox 34 and later:

> The Storage Inspector is disabled by default. Enable it in the Developer Tools Settings.

[image]

> The Storage Inspector enables you to inspect various types of storages that a web page can use. Currently it can be used to inspect the following storage types:

```
Cookies – All the cookies created by the page or any iframes inside of the page. Cookies created as a part of response of network calls are also listed, but only for calls that happened while the tool is open.
Local Storage – All local storage items created by the page or any iframes inside the page.
Session Storage – All session storage items created by the page or any iframes inside the page.
IndexedDB – All indexedDB databases created by the page or any iframes inside the page, their Object Stores and the items stored in these Object Stores.
```

Open the Developer Tools, then Click the fourth icon from the left on the top right menu:

[image]

**References**

- [Firefox Developer Tools, episode 34](http://bytearrays.com/firefox-developer-tools-episode-34/)
- [MDN: Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I couldn't see any IDB object created in Chromium / Firefox.

The problem: I was looking on the homepage of the App.

[image]

It turns out that I had to go to the location of the script `website/idb-test` (which contains index.js) that creates the IDB to get it executed and be able to see the DB. You may place the script in some place where it gets executed when loading the homepage, or not. Just keep it in mind.

[image]

And Firefox / Waterfox

[image]

If you don't see the Application (Chromium) / Storage tab (Firefox), look into the 'Web Developer' settings.

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises simply when executing the htm or html page on a memory extension card whish is plugged into the computer (Secure Digital Storage Device), or on an external SSD, while the Firefox developer installation is on C:/.    This simply means that the full detail of the domain of the interpreted page, including the drive in the path, is not correctly taken into account in the the Firefox developer in contrast to the Chrome developer.   Just move your JAVASCRIPT programming page to a directory on the drive from which the browser is installed (ie drive C: )  and all works just fine.